# Register Windows program with the mailto protocol programmatically

Tags: windows, mailto

How do I make it so `mailto:` links will be registered with my program?

How would I then handle that event in my program?

Most of the solutions I found from a quick Google search are how to do this manually, but I need to do this automatically for users of my program if they click a button, such as "set as default email client".

#Edit:
Removed reference to the Delphi Programming Language, because the answer is independent of your language.

Comment: Here is the official Microsoft Solution to programmatically change the default mail client. It's Visual Basic, but I hope the concept is clear from this: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299853](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299853)

Comment: From your link: "This is separate from the default Web browser or e-mail client that is used to start arbitrary URLs from anywhere in the system."

That's also another thing I was wondering, but not really the answer to this question.

Comment: Please note the Microsoft kb article link is no longer valid as Microsoft has seen fit to remove it and they never allowed archiving in the wayback machine. Until someone supplies the info, please refer to this excellent discussion: https://superuser.com/questions/1045349/where-windows-10-stores-default-email-app-in-its-registry

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*@Dillie-O: Your answer put me in the right direction (I should have expected it to just be a registry change) and I got this working. But I'm going to mark this as the answer because I'm going to put some additional information that I found while working on this.*

The solution to this question really doesn't depend on what programming language you're using, as long as there's some way to modify Windows registry settings.

Finally, here's the answer:

- To associate a program with the mailto protocol for **all users** on a computer, change the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command Default value to:
  "*Your program's executable*" "%1"
- To [associate a program with the mailto protocol for the **current user**](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/permail.htm), change the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command Default value to:
  "*Your program's executable*" "%1"

The %1 will be replaced with the entire mailto URL. For example, given the link:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">Email me</a>
```

The following will be executed:
"*Your program's executable*" "mailto:user@example.com"

Update (via comment by shellscape):
As of Windows 8, this method no longer works as expected. Win8 enforces the following key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associati‌​ons\URLAssociations\‌​MAILTO\UserChoice for which the ProgID of the selected app is hashed and can't be forged. It's a royal PITA.

Comment: Have you checked whether now you can mark this as *the* answer? I don't know the minimum reputation required.

Comment: As of Windows 8, this method no longer works as expected. Win8 enforces the following key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations\MAILTO\UserChoice for which the ProgID of the selected app is hashed and can't be forged. It's a royal PITA

Answer (score 13):

From what I've seen, there are a few registry keys that set the default mail client. One of them is:

System Key: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command]`

Value Name: `(Default)`

Data Type: `REG_SZ` (String Value)

Value Data: `Mail program command-line`.

I'm not familiar  with `Delphi 7`, but I'm sure there are some *registry editing libraries* there that you could use to modify this value.

Some places list more than this *key*, others just this key, so you may need to test a little bit to find the proper one(s).