# How do you set a custom application as default email client in Windows in code

Tags: delphi, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Register Windows program with the mailto protocol programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically)

I would like to set an in house email client written in Delphi as the default email client for mailto: using code.  Is it possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

General answer for [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx).

Or how to register your application for URLs starting with `your_protocol:`