# Force the browser to open an FTP Client on ftp:// link

Tags: browser, ftp

Is possible to force the browser to open a link of type

```
<a href="ftp://my.ftp.com">FTP </a>
```

to the system default ftp client for examples cyberduck?

Comment: that's like trying to force the client to open the system default browser when clicking an http link while you are browsing with a non default for example. It can't be done.

Comment: a from HTML. that wasn't the original question :-) .. anyway: luckily you can't change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. While each browser handles non-HTTP protocols differently, most allow the *user* to choose the behavior - e.g. with Opera, you have the option of opening in browser, invoking the default application or setting a custom application.

The only way you could do this would be in IE with a trusted ActiveX control, but that's a rather horrible hack.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option, but it's a permanent option. You can change the associated protocol for the type ftp; more information about that can be found here [Register Windows program with the mailto protocol programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically) (although they're discussing the mailto protocol - but it's basically the same).

Comment: where "you" means "you the computer user", not "you the page designer" - the reasons this can't and shouldn't be changed remotely are hopefully obvious

Comment: No, that is basically _not_ the same. The problem is that those entries are intended for programs that themselves cannot handle the protocol. Many web browsers can handle FTP; mail is a bigger problem because it requires the users mail account.

Comment: @piskvor +1 indeed, but that wasn't the original question therefor the answer is a bit off

Comment: @MSalters it *is* basically the same you just change the registry setting for the protocol >> what program is associated with that particular protocol regardless of the built-in functions of IE (or other browser).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's entirely up to client to decide, how exactly to handle `ftp` protocol.

Comment: i've made a typo so the question doesn't show how I want.
I'm talking about an HTML link that specify ftp as protocol in href param.
(I've edit the question)