# Override MAPI in Windows

Tags: windows, email, default, mapi

I'm looking for some information how to replace the default email program within Windows. So far I've been able to find limited information about changing the registry keys to point to a custom coded DLL. Microsoft mentions that there is a MAPI stub which is saved as Windows\System32\MAPI32.dll and there are functions that need to be implemented but not much detail on how it must be done.

I'll be writing the main program in C# but get the feeling I'll need to write the custom MAPI DLL in unmanaged C/C++

Any links or insight would be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of

1. modifying default email program is not related to DLL.  [See KB 299853](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299853).  The sample is in VB but you can easily change it to C#.
2. associate the mailto: protocol to your program, which is [already discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peon for the info.

Part of my research brought me information about Mozilla's Thunderbird. 
Thunderbird may not fully implement Simple MAPI as many people have mentioned. However it gives a great outline of the DLL stub that needs to be overridden.
Anyone looking into creating a default email client, or at least acts like a default email client should look at the Thunderbird source code ( available off Mozilla's website ).

Also, install Thunderbird. It creates all of the proper registry changes that you'll also need to make.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074930/windows-application-crash-issue-with-dllmain-c

use registry to change default email client. And code from the link will help you to run your code.

Code is in c++.