# Is it possible to determine what a user's default email client is?

Tags: html, outlook, gmail

I have `mailto:` link in a web app that includes 'CC' and 'subject' fields. I would like these fields to have different values if the link will be opened int outlook or gmail. Is it possible to programmatically determine which email client is the user's default?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Gmail is web based, and you need a local app to handle the mailto url. See [How to register custom program to handle mailto protocol on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105258/how-to-register-custom-program-to-handle-mailto-protocol-on-windows-7)

Secondly, you would need to access the registry key to determine the mailto url handler, and you cannot do that from a script running inside a browser.