# Process.Start not working on live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, mailto

Im trying to open the email client after a user accepts a disclaimer in a popup box whenever they click email someone. It works on local but will not work on live.

```
public void btnEmail_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
     Process.Start("mailto:blah@blah.com");
}
```

I realize now this will not work correctly obviously. Is there a way to do what im looking for with javascript?

Comment: Live *site*? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: Is this WinForms? ASP.NET? Or what?

Comment: You intend a webserver to start its installed email application every time a user clicks a button on a web page?

Comment: It is Asp.net. Im trying to have a popup box be accepted before an email is able to be sent.

Comment: @oded yes Exactly. I know it doesnt seem correct but thats what my client wants for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at a JavaScript solution

Comment: @Snake3ite - I think you will find that's not what the client wants. They might say the words, but you need to dig deeper. They may want and email to be sent every time.

Comment: no ive specifically asked them. thats what they want.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work.  The server would try to open its email client as the NETWORK SERVICE account on the server (or whatever the identify is used for the ASP.NET application).  What exactly is it supposed to do after that?

Comment: This is Supposed to when clicked on "Email Someone" a popup box opens with a disclaimer the user has to accept. Then if the user clicks ok it should open the default mail client with the email already inputted in the email message.

Comment: Something is VERY WRONG here.

Comment: You do realize there is a `SmtpClient` class?

Comment: Anyone have a better idea on how to do waht im looking for?

Comment: @Snake3ite: I just told you in my previous comment. Does that do what you need?

Comment: Wrong understanding of web application and desktop. Calling Process.Start on server side won't launch mail app on client side.

Comment: @leppie It does in a way but i do not have a textbox to type the email message. I could add one but doesnt seem to be what my client wants. I think it is the only solution here tho.

Comment: @LexLi Ahhh that makes alot more sense then.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Comment: How about `<a href='mailto:blah@blah.com'>Click me</a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to register the `mailto` Protocol handler for that to work off the box like that.

look at [Register Windows program with the mailto protocol programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically) on how it can be accomplished thru code.

### or

If you want to open Outlook and send out a mail to someone -

`Outlook /c ipm.note /m blah@blah.com`

Thru Code -

```
string app = "Outlook.exe";
string arguments = @"/c ipm.note /m blah@blah.com";

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(app, arguments);
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **probabbly** is that your client doesn't have default *Mail Client* setupped on machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No im testing on my machine and i do have Outlook defaulted

Comment: @Snake3ite: so porbbably your default browser is not connected to mailclient.

Comment: @Snake3ite: for example for IE8 [How to Configure Email in Internet Explorer 8

Read more: How to Configure Email in Internet Explorer 8 | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_5879297_configure-email-internet-explorer-8.html#ixzz1sOhh8rac](http://www.ehow.com/how_5879297_configure-email-internet-explorer-8.html)

Comment: No, the problem is that there's nobody logged in to the server to see the email window open.

Comment: @scott.korin: how did you figure out that? I don't see any notion of that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, just set the location.href

```
<input type="button" value="Send E-mall" onclick="location.href='mailto:blah@blah.com';">
```