# URI scheme launching

Tags: windows, delphi, uri

I've been given a task to create a protocol similar to callto:, that - upon clicking on a link with it - would automatically launch an installed aplication.

I followed the [microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how a scheme should look like.

My scheme looks like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   slican
       URL Protocol = ""
       DefaultIcon (Default) = "C:\Users\Okabe\Desktop\slican\SlicanP.exe,1"
       shell
            open
                command (Default) = "C:\Users\Okabe\Desktop\slican\SlicanP.exe" "%1""
```

I thought that was all and tested it with

```
 <a href="slican:test">test link</a>
 <a href="slican:0049325778421">test telephone link</a>
```

There was no reaction whatsoever. Internet Explorer asked me if I want to search for a program that can open the content and Chrome responded with nothing, as if I clicked javascript:void(0).

How to get that worked?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is not true.  If you read the [URI spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), [section 3.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2) in particular, the presence of `//` would turn `test` into a remote hostname.  `slican:test` is proper syntax for invoking a custom app on the local machine with `test` as an input parameter.

Comment: @Remy, didn't know that meaning. Thanks! Still, even without knowing the meaning of those slashes, I could remember one of the most commonly used locally invoked protocols, `mailto`. I should have think twice...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The registration you show works perfectly fine for me when I try it on Windows 7.  The local app I registered in place of SlicanP.exe ran fine when I invoked a `slican:` URL from the `Start | Run` menu, and from within the address bar of Windows Explorer.  So the registration works.

Do be aware that Internet Explorer runs in a lower integrity security context, so it may not have rights to run local programs.  When I tried to click on an HTML link to a `slican:` URL, or type a `slican:` URL in the address bar, IE had trouble executing the local app (even after prompting for permission).  I had to run IE as an administrator, then the local app ran just fine.

Also, you really should not be creating a `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slican` key directly.  Create a `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\slican` (current user only) or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\slican` (all users) instead.  Refer to MSDN for more details:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx)

[Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx)

**Update**: Since it works in Windows 7, Microsoft probably changed how URL schemes are registered in Windows 8. For instance, phone/store apps use URI activation:

[URI activation (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx).

[URI activation (HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx)

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916.aspx) says there are two ways to register a custom URI scheme:

> Internet Explorer uses two mechanisms for registering new pluggable protocol handlers. The first method is to register a URI scheme name and its associated application so that all attempts to navigate to a URI using that scheme launch the application (for example, registering applications to handle mailto: or news: URIs). The second method uses the Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols API, which allows you to define new protocols by mapping the URI scheme to a class.

You are doing the first.  Try using the second instead.

However, I just noticed that "Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols" is listed on MSDN in the "Legacy APIs" section, and it has the following note:

> Third-party protocol implementations won't load in Windows Store apps using JavaScript, **or in the Internet Explorer in the new Windows UI.**

So it may or may not work in Windows 8.

**Update**: I just found this:

[Guidelines for file types and URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700321.aspx)

> In Windows 8, the relationship between apps and the file types they support differs from previous versions of Windows.

[Walkthrough: using Windows 8 Custom Protocol Activation](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html)

> The file type and protocol association model has changed in Windows 8. Apps are no longer able to programmatically set themselves as the default handler for a file type or protocol. Instead, now the user always controls what the default handler is for a file type or protocol.
>
> Your app can use existing protocols for communication, such as mailto, or create a custom protocol. The protocol activation extension enables you to define a custom protocol or register to handle an existing protocol.

Also have a look at this:

[Setting mailto: protocol handler programmatically in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238446/)

And this:

[Default Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154.aspx)

Comment: So what would be the cause that IE and Chrome won't launch my SlicanP.exe? Chrome won't even pop-up a question if I want to run an external app, like IE does...? No browser reacts whatsoever...

Comment: Did you restart the browsers, or even the OS, after making changes in the Registry?

Comment: Yes, I did, that's why I was surprised.

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Windows are you using?  What version of IE?  Of Chrome?

Comment: Windows 8, Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: Since it works in Windows 7, Microsoft probably changed how URL schemes are registered in Windows 8.  For instance, phone/store apps use [URI activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx).

Comment: Something I just noticed - "Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols" is listed on MSDN in the "Legacy APIs" section, and it has the [following note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916.aspx): "Third-party protocol implementations won't load in Windows Store apps using JavaScript, **or in the Internet Explorer in the new Windows UI.**".

Comment: Yup, Windows 8 changes the rules.  I updated my answer with various links.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I just need to struggle with adapting it with my Delphi 7 app...

Comment: Sorry for necropost, But is it still valid for windows 10? Or maybe there is difference between win 10, win 8 and previous version?

Answer (score 1):

if you go to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

You can edit the Local State file

Search for protocol_handler

The syntax here is a key value pair. I usually copy two mailto: and make sure that you set your protocols to false. This will mean that chrome will treat your new protocols as URI_Handler events

Comment: This seems to be no longer valid. Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit), the Local State file does not have a protocol_handler section.

Answer (score 0):

If you have troubles with configuring custom URI scheme, you can compare your own configuration with existing one. For example, "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/mailto" - most likely you have it already in your system.