# How to launch a Windows Universal App from winform

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to run a Windows Universal App from my winform using the following code but unfortunately it opens the documents folder. I am new in UWP app development. Is it the correct way to launch a UWP app?

```
Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.SDKSamples.CameraAdvancedCapture.CS_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();
```

Answer (score 10):

You really have two questions here:

1. How do you launch a protocol from a WinForms app
2. How to properly launch a UWP app.

To launch a protocol from your WinForms app use the Process object with *UseShellExecute = true*. Don't try launching it with Explorer.exe as the process.

The best way to launch an app is via protocol, so long as the app defines one. If you control the app then you can define a protocol as shown by @Romasz: [Handle URI activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation)

The shell:appsFolder trick you used on your command line is a handy scripting hack, but it's not documented or guaranteed. Don't ship code dependent on it.

Once you have a protocol you can launch it with Process.Start:

Here's the shell hack to launch the People app:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName =  startInfo.FileName =  @"shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

Since the People app [defines a documented protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-people-apps#ms-people-uri-scheme-reference) it'd be better to launch it that way. This can also let us choose which contact we want:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = @"ms-people:viewcontact?PhoneNumber=8675309";
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

The correct way to launch a UWP app that doesn't define a protocol is to use the IApplicationActivationManager. This is what the shell will use internally, and it can give you more control over what you're launching and how.

There is a stackoverflow Q/A on using IApplicationActivationManager from C# at [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c)

Comment: will this work if Powershell is blocked in the machine for the current user and available to admin users only?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Automate launching Windows 10 UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe" MyPackageName_ph1m9x8skttmg!AppId
```

Where `MyPackageName_ph1m9x8skttmg` is the `Package family name` of your UWP app and `AppId` is the `Application Id` in your Package.appxmanifest file under `<Applications>` xml element.

Comment: Windows Kits is available for those who installed Windows SDK for development. It's not showing on non-developer laptop

Comment: This command saved my day, I struggled to get the app id though. we can get it from the UWP projects Package.apxmanifest -> Package tab -> Package Family Name. Or run the power-shell command get-StartApps | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'appname'}

Answer (score 0):

You can [register the app for the URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) and then activate it. Inside the app you will have to handle [OnActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242330) event.

As for some more information [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24458845/2681948) can be helpful.