# How to launch UWP app from windows forms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I am running windows forms,in that forms have some integer.I want to launch UWP app from that form .Already i have UWP and windows forms,then i have to call whenever forms run successfully that time app should launch the integer of form result.

is there any idea for this app launch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch a Windows Universal App from winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887366/how-to-launch-a-windows-universal-app-from-winform)

Answer (score 1):

> How to launch UWP app from windows forms using C#

You could use [`Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) `LaunchUriAsync`  to launch uwp app from WinForm app. And first we need register protocol for UWP app. For detail steps please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation). Then we need call Launcher api from WinForm app. For detail steps you could refer this [tutorial](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at `Process.Start` ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I looked at process start also.However it does not sole my problem.I have UWP in folder.How i will call that folder from windows form?i launched the app when i click the button

Comment: private void btnGetUID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\uwp-kio\\car\\carl";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                myProcess.Start();

            }
        }