# c#: How to popup uwp project in winform

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to popup a **UWP** project when I click a button in a **Winform** project 
I tried to pop up WPF, but it didn't work in UWP. In WinForm I can't add a reference to the UWP project, so I don't know what to do.
The amount of information on UWP is small, so it is difficult to search.

How to popup UWP in Winform?

Comment: Do you mean launch a UWP app when you click a button from the Winforms app?

Comment: yes, right and it's in same solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch a UWP app from a WinForms app, you will need to register
a Protocol for your UWP app first. It will be used as a URI scheme name for your UWP app. Then you could call the [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-22000) in your WinForms app to launch the UWP app.

You could also refer to Nico's reply here: [How to launch UWP app from windows forms using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357074/how-to-launch-uwp-app-from-windows-forms-using-c-sharp)