# Launching Win 10 Movie & TV app (Films & TV in UK?)

Tags: vb6

I've been launching good, old Windows Media Player (wmplayer.exe) from my trusty VB6 app for many years using code such as:

```
stPlayer = "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
stMyVideo = "D:\temp\myvideo.mp4"
stCommandLine = stPlayer & " " & stMyVideo
inShellID = Shell(stCommandLine, vbNormalFocus)
```

but in recent times have found a few issues with wmplayer and would like to switch to using a more recent, reliable app such as the Windows **Movie & TV** app (this may be called the **Film & TV** app in the UK?) that seems to play my MP4 files with no issues at all.

However, I don't really get this newfangled Windows app stuff apart from to know that they're not traditional .exe files that I know how to call from a command line. Or are they?

Is anyone able to help me with how I can get VB6 to open my MP4 video using Movie & TV app?

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41887366/11683?

Comment: They are started via URLs as the exe file name changes as it's updated. This answer lists all URLs https://superuser.com/questions/1554492/where-are-the-windows-10-stock-apps-located