# Cannot bring a process to the front

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I'm currently developing software in VB.NET (using Visual Studio 2019).

I need to bring a process to the front.
I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub BringInternet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BringInternet.Click
    Dim mngcls As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_Process")
    Do
        For Each instance As ManagementObject In mngcls.GetInstances()
            If instance("Name").ToString = "msedge.exe" Then
                Dim ID As Integer = instance("ProcessId")
                MsgBox(ID)

                AppActivate(ID)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Next
    Loop While False
End Sub
```

Sometimes it's working but most of the time it doesn't work. I've already done some research about this but I found nothing about this bug.

Comment: First of all, what's the point of the `Do...While` loop? It will only run once anyway.

Comment: To exit when the process is found. Else I have an error because I try to call the same process more than once.

Comment: You could remove the `Do...While` and just `Exit For` on the `For Each` loop instead.

Comment: Again, your `Do...While` loop will only run once (because of `Loop While False`). You should either change the condition (if you really need the loop; but I don't think you need it) or you should get rid of it and use `Exit For` instead of `Exit Do`.

Comment: I've been remove my loop and replace by Exit For but it's the same.

Comment: Surprising it works at all, Edge is a UWP app.  Use `Process.Start("microsoft-edge:")` instead.  [Backgrounder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41906116/17034)

Comment: @HansPassant Not the new Chromium-based version though: https://www.askvg.com/microsoft-to-retire-internet-explorer-and-legacy-microsoft-edge-web-browsers-soon.

Comment: It starts the Chrome-based one on my machine.

Comment: @Hans It does indeed (I'm not sure why) but is it a UWP app? It's located under `Program Files (x86)` and works well with `ShowWindow()` and `SetForegroundWindow()`. That's a little odd. It's always great to get your insights though, so please let me know if there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used `AppActivate` (back in the VB6 days). Apparently, it's simply a wrapper around the `SetForegroundWindow()` Win32 function, meaning that it only brings the window to front (if it's already in a *restored* state) but it doesn't restore it if minimized.

In order to restore the window and then bring it to front, you need to call `ShowWindow()` first and then `SetForegroundWindow()`.

First, add this class to your project:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ProcessHelper
    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function ShowWindow(handle As IntPtr, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function IsIconic(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Const SW_RESTORE As Integer = 9

    Public Shared Sub BringProcessToFront(processName As String)
        ' Modern browsers run on multiple processes.
        ' We need to find the ones that have a WindowHandle.
        Dim processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).
                            Where(Function(p) p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero)
        For Each p As Process In processes
            If BringProcessToFront(p) Then Exit Sub
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function BringProcessToFront(p As Process) As Boolean
        Dim windowHandle As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle
        If IsIconic(windowHandle) Then
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_RESTORE)
        End If

        Return SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
ProcessHelper.BringProcessToFront("msedge") ' Tip: Use the process name without ".exe".
```

Comment: Thanks you. It's work. I've been blocked for two days.