# Execute user actions

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a C# web application.  I am hoping to be able to add a hyperlink/button and if a user clicks it, then another application is opened and the relevant screen is found.  For example, if a user clicks on person ID 1, then the other application is opened and the person screen is opened with id 1 displayed.

I have thought about this and Googled it and I believe it could possibly be done with Selenium, however I only have experience testing web apps with Selenium and the other app is a desktop application.

Is it possible to execute user actions like this?

Comment: Does the application you are trying to open support linking directly to resources? If not, are you able to modify its source code? It should have a [registered URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) similar to `anotherapp:people?id=1` which you can then [navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate?view=net-5.0) to.

Comment: As detailed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53065239/14956277), your target application will likely need administrator privileges, so that's another consideration. Also, [Internet Explorer may need some help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24458845/14956277) launching your custom schema if you plan to support it.

Comment: More information and possible dupe target: [Start an application from a URL and get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445017/start-an-application-from-a-url-and-get-data).