# Opening default email when clicking on UWP email hyperlink

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to learn UWP/XAML, and am trying to open the default email client when an email link is clicked. Here is what I have

```
                <TextBlock FontSize="36"     Foreground="Navy">
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="36">
                        Contact This Person
                    </Run>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="30">
                        Bob Smith
                    </Run>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="30">
                        123 Fake Street
                    </Run>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    <Run Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="30">
                        FooBar, Foo
                    </Run>
                    <LineBreak/>

                    <Run Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="30">
                       5551212
                    </Run>
                    <LineBreak/>

                    <Hyperlink  NavigateUri="mailto:test@blahblah.com" >Email Bob</Hyperlink>

                </TextBlock>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

When I click on the email link, I get a popup asking me if I want to switch to Chrome. Do I need .cs code, or can this all be handled in the XAML?

Answer (score 3):

By default the MAILTO: protocol is not associated with a mail client.

A client can associate an application application with the protocol by selecting the application in the dialog you mentioned. Doing this will create registry keys at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations\‌​MAILTO\UserChoice` to store the URL association. The value of  what needs to be set in these keys depends if you are pre-windows 8 or later as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically).

So to summarize, you are seeing that dialog because you haven't set a default mail client to handle urls with the `mailto:` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a handler for the Click event, then use the Launcher class in code-behind.

XAML:

```
<Hyperlink Click="ContactHyperlink_Click">
    example@example.com
</Hyperlink>
```

Code-behind:

```
private async void ContactHyperlink_Click(Hyperlink sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Documents.HyperlinkClickEventArgs args)
{
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:example@example.com?subject=Message from My App"));
}
```